# Is the weight of a projectile launched from earth and while still flying in the atmospheric sky transferred to the ground?

Tags: forces, pressure, fluid-statics, projectile

Raised by [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/519504/).

**Q1.** Is the weight of a projectile like a bullet or a ballistic missile (atmospheric flight trajectory) transferred to the ground?

Of course i know that if the projectile was out of sky there is no doubt that it can be seen as a separate object like satellites or the moon but if a mass goes in a ballistic path inside the atmosphere (specially near ground) does it's wight transferred to the ground?

**Q2.** what about jet propelled rockets like space launch vehicle while they are near ground?

Comment: Even after leaving the atmosphere, the weight of a rising rocket can be transferred to the ground. The exhaust gases fly downward into the atmosphere, which slows them down with an upward force. The reaction force on the atmosphere is downward, and is transferred to the ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any object in the atmosphere, that is not in freefall, is ultimately transferring it's weight to the ground. A normal bullet fired from a gun is essentially in freefall once it leaves the gun. After leaving the gun, it has no lift, it starts falling. It may have upward momentum which it will immediately start losing. It's upward acceleration is transferred to the ground by the gun's recoil, until it leaves the barrel. While in a freefall trajectory it does not transfer weight to the ground. A powered missile, or rocket, is a different matter. While under power, or using lift surfaces, it will be pushing gasses downwards to create lift, these downward moving gasses will eventually cause increased pressure on the ground. Even lighter than air balloons displace air which will increase pressure on the ground. The ground pressure differences involved will eventually equal the amount of lift created.